# How to grab to image scrollable QML item?

Tags: image, qt, qml

I need to save a QML item as image. I use grabToImage() method (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) and it works well when my item is completely on the screen. But the item is a ScrollView and sometimes it's parts are outside the view. And I want to have full item on image. is it possible?

Here is an example to my problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Example")

    Button {
        text: qsTr("Save as image")
        onClicked: {
            scheme.grabToImage(function(result) {
                result.saveToFile("temp.png")
            });
        }
    }

    ScrollView {
        id: scheme
        y: 50
        clip: true
        width: 400
        height: 200

        contentWidth: rect.width
        contentHeight: rect.height

        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 600
            height: 400
            color: "gray"
            Rectangle {
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "blue"
            }
            Rectangle {
                x: 500
                y: 300
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of grabbing the ScrollView (which only has size of 400x200), grab the child of ScrollView (which is the full 600x400).

```
rect.grabToImage(function(result) {
                result.saveToFile("temp.png")
            });
```

Comment: So easy! Thanks a lot!